# Keep Sink Columns in Copy Activity when Source Columns less than Sink Columns

Tags: mapping, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity in Datafactory that dynamically maps the columns between files in tables A and B. Both tables, A and B are .parquet. Table A has 8 columns, and these 8 columns are mapped using a mappings json variable to 8 of the 12 Columns in table B. This json is a the output of an activity that creates the mappings variable to be consumed in the copy activity. However, when I run the pipeline, all mappings work fine but the non mapped columns originally in sink (4) - disappear. Is there a way to preserve these columns in the activity and keep them unchanged ?

The desired output would be the sink table B with the same 12 columns, 8 of those with the data that was copied in the activity and the last 4 should be kept NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataFlow Activity. In Derived column’s settings Select Columns. Here select unmapped columns.

In the sink do the required mapping.

[image]

Comment: This has something to be dynamic. Would this approach work without manually specifying which columns we don't need to map?